# How to resolve "Table not initialized" issue while serving USE4 model in tensorflow serving?

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, tensorflow2.0, tensorflow-serving

So i prepared a keras model including USE4 using the below link :
https://tfhub.dev/google/universal-sentence-encoder-large/4

Using tensorflow 2.3, i added it to my model and saved the model

```
tf.saved_model.save(
model,
export_dir= '/directory/model/1',
)
```

Once served in docker, I'm able to get the metadata but predict request is not working. Here is the request :

```
{"inputs":{"text":["Hello"]}}
```

Response :

```
{ "error": "[_Derived_]{{function_node __inference_pruned_16231}} {{function_node __inference_pruned_16231}} Table not initialized.\n\t [[{{node text_preprocessor_1/hash_table_Lookup/hash_table_Lookup/LookupTableFindV2}}]]\n\t [[StatefulPartitionedCall/StatefulPartitionedCall/sequential/keras_layer/StatefulPartitionedCall/StatefulPartitionedCall/StatefulPartitionedCall]]" }
```

I read here https://github.com/awslabs/amazon-sagemaker-examples/issues/773#issuecomment-509433290 that this issue can be resolved in older tf versions by using the command tf.tables_initializer() in the old tf.saved_model.simple_save() function. But in 2.3.0 what's the alternative?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Could you retry with version 5 of that model ([link](https://tfhub.dev/google/universal-sentence-encoder-large/5))? Your issue looks related to [this](https://github.com/tensorflow/hub/issues/409) GitHub issue, which was solved by using v5 of the model. If that doesn't solve it, a minimal snippet to reproduce the issue would be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

the function 'tf.saved_model.simple_save()' has a parameter 'legacy_init_op' with default value 'None'. To avoid the problem 'Table not initialized' after model deployed with docker, maybe you can try this:

```
legacy_init_op = tf.group(tf.compat.v1.tables_initializer(), name='init_all_tables2')
tf.saved_model.simple_save(sess,
                       your_model_path, 
                       inputs={"xxx": xxx}, 
                       outputs={"xxx": xxx},
                       legacy_init_op=legacy_init_op
                      )
```